# How to decrease java heap size?

Tags: java, memory, jboss

I've got an app which is running on `JBoss`. The server's RAM is too low (about 2gb), so I need to decrease `Java` heap size. Also I've got 2 versions of Java : system version(`1.4.2`) and `1.7.0` for `JBoss 7` only.
So, how can I decrease Java heap size properly?

Comment: Are you getting an error message about heap, or is the java process using up too much memory on the server?

Comment: No, I'm not getting an error. My production server was working well, until I've installed JBoss. So, I decided to decrease Java heap size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the heap size in jboss startup file, edit bat or sh file and search for -Xms and change it to your required size.

Answer (score 5):

There are two flags to control the heap size: -Xms128m will *start* your heap at 128 megs, and -Xmx1g controls the maximum size (here, it would set it to 1 gig).

Answer (score 1):

> Default size of Heap space  in Java is 128MB on most of 32 bit Sun's JVM and default values of heap size parameters on 64-bit systems have been increased up by approximately 30%.

You can use

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize
```

to check your default size.

[Read more](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/java-heap-space-memory-size-jvm.html#ixzz31VTokmWH)

You can change size of heap space by using JVM options -Xms and -Xmx. Xms denotes starting size of Heap while -Xmx denotes maximum size of Heap in Java.
You can use
`java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M YourApp`

Or edit the /bin/run.sh|exe file by searching for “Sun JVM memory allocation pool parameters” and changing the JAVA_OPTS line:

> set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -server -Xms1152m -Xmx1152m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
>   -XX:MaxNewSize=128m